# What type of constrained boundary value problem is this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a **homogeneous second-order differential equation** [in function $y(x)$] with **variable coefficients** - with no given specific functional forms for $a(x)$ or $b(x)$ - given as follows:

$$y\hspace{0.01in}''+a(x)\hspace{0.01in}y\hspace{0.01in}'+b(x)\hspace{0.01in}y=0$$

given the **boundary conditions**,

$$y(1)=1,\text{ and $\,\,$}y(0)=\alpha\hspace{0.01in}y\hspace{0.01in}'(0)$$

where, **$\alpha$ is a constant**. Clearly, the second boundary value/condition is in form of a constraint; from what I understand, this type of boundary value problem is called the **Mixed Boundary Value Problem** (or alternatively, the **Robin Boundary Value Problem**). Now, what is the ***most optimal method*** (in terms of ***computational cost***) to solve this problem **numerically**?

Thanks for the help folks!

Comment: How many boundary conditions, two or three? Are numerical values $y'(0), y(0),  y(1) $  given?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say it is most optimal.

Either separately solve the differential equation and input the boundary conditions,

$$ Y(x)=\alpha\hspace{0.01in}Y\hspace{0.01in}'(x), Y(0) = Y_i = y(0), y(1) = 1 $$

or, solve them together numerically as a *coupled* differential equations,like say:

$$y(1)=1,\text{ and $\,\,$}y(0)=\alpha\hspace{0.01in}y\hspace{0.01in}'(0) = 0.2 $$

Comment: In your case, $Y_i$ is unknown. Also, the numerical values for $y\hspace{0.01in}'(0)$ or $y(0)$ are not given.

Answer (score 0):

I think herein the **correct way** is given. In principle, it is a method to solve the system analytically. One can find an optimal numerical method easily since the overall method simply includes **solving two differential equations independently**, and then **linearly combining the results** with an appropriate pre-factor.

**Link:** http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111107063/module4/lecture4/lecture4.pdf